# How do I stop mousemove?

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, drag

I have created a JS function to drag an item left & right. I need to stop the dragging after clicking a button. How do I stop mousemove?

I've tried `$('.draggable').off('mousemove');` and `e.stopPropagation();`, but neither worked for me.

A JSFiddle is worth a thousand words, please see the issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/k2k928j1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're doing

```
$('.draggable').parents().on('mousemove', function(e) { ... });
```

and

```
$('.draggable').off('mousemove');
```

The `off` call isn't on the same element as the `on` call. Change it to

```
$('.draggable').parents().off('mousemove');
```

and it works.

...although you really ought to be storing the handler and removing it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the "draggable" class.

`$('.draggable').removeClass('draggable');`

https://jsfiddle.net/a1vvmszq/

Comment: +1 because you are totally right. I accepted the other answer though, because it answered my specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your jsfiddle:

```
$('#stop').on('click',function(){
  //$('.draggable').off('mousemove');
  $('.thing').off(); // Removes all event handlers.
});
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to stop the box from moving.

Comment: Did you edit the code & then click the stop link, before attempting to move the box? It works for me when I edit your code.

Comment: I don't know why jQuery's not allowing this code to run: `$('.draggable').off('mousemove');` nor this code `$('.thing').off('mousemove');` when their API docs show that it's perfectly legit to do that. (See the additional notes here: http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) It might be a bug in their library.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `mouseup`, use the `mouseleave` event. https://jsfiddle.net/k2k928j1/2/

Comment: Hi Oscar, sorry, this is difficult to describe. I want the box to continue moving during what would be the mouseleave event. I only want it to stop after clicking the button.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Maybe you want something like the following: https://jsfiddle.net/k2k928j1/3/